# Cannot follow tutorial (https://developer.gnome.org/anjuta-build-tutorial/stable/create-autotools.html.en)

Tags: c

https://developer.gnome.org/anjuta-build-tutorial/stable/create-autotools.html.en
I have got to section 3.1.4, question 10. I run the command make install in the directory /usr/local/bin. I get the following error: make: *** No rule to make target 'install'. Stop.

Please help.

Comment: You should run it in the directory where you built the library (the same directory where ran `configure` and `make`). It will (probably) *install* to `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a whole makefile? But right now I can tell - you should check that "install" target already exists. So, check Makefile whether it contains a

```
install: (anything there)
```

line. If not, there is no such target and so make has right. Probably you should use just "make" command to compile and then use it as is or install yourself, manually.

Install is not any standard of make, it is just a common target, that could exists, but not necessary.

Source: ["No rule to make target 'install'"... But Makefile exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672364/no-rule-to-make-target-install-but-makefile-exists) by Tomir Rogi Szawok