# Pytorch Build from Source gives Error make: *** No rule to make target 'install'. Stop

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, pytorch

I am following [this guide](https://medium.com/hardware-interfacing/how-to-install-pytorch-v4-0-on-raspberry-pi-3b-odroids-and-other-arm-based-devices-91d62f2933c7) to build Pytorch from scratch on a Raspberry Pi3B. For some reason, there is an error:

```sh
Building wheel torch-1.2.0a0+f13fadd
-- Building version 1.2.0a0+f13fadd
cmake --build . --target install --config Release -- -j 4
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

when I call `python3 setup.py build`. I am running Python version 3.5 and I am unsure why this seems to be failing.

Comment: This problem went away after a complete reinstall of the OS and using CondaBerry. Don't know why but something to try for anyone who gets the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem with reference to [this link](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/16602#issuecomment-460348240).

This error happened at my second installation attempt. During the first I forgot to install the c++ compiler and got `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` not found. With a proper compiler installed, the second attempt gave me the "No rule to make target 'install'" error as mentioned in the question.

The problem was solved by removing the `build/` directory and re-run `python setup.py install`.

So it seems this is caused by the cached build information.

Answer (score 5):

Recently I encountered this error so after some research, in 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46987554/12164529
someone mentioned something about cache.
Therefore I guess that's because of some CMake cache behavior, so I run this command:

```
sudo USE_ROCM=1 USE_LMDB=1 USE_OPENCV=1 MAX_JOBS=15 python setup.py clean
```

And the error went away.

ps. This is my first answer on stackoverflow, and I'm not sure if this is a good one, but I hope it helps people find here.